# Table with different colors removes vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: tables, color

I have a table in my documentation, where i'm switching the rowcolor between white(default) and gray. Those rows, where the color is changed with `\rowcolor{gray}`, disabling the horizontal and vertical lines?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{7cm}|}
    \hline  
    \rowcolor{Blackgray}
    \textcolor{white}{\textit{Column 1}}                &       \textcolor{white}{\textit{Column 2}}                        \\      \hline 
    Fooo -- Bar                                         &       Some text here with enum:
                                                                \begin{itemize}
                                                                    \item Item1
                                                                    \item Item2
                                                                    \item ...
                                                                \end{itemize}                                               \\      \hline
    \rowcolor{Gray} 
    Foo -- Baar                                         &       Some text here....                                          \\      \hline
    Fooo -- Baaaar                                      &       Some other text here                                        \\      \hline
    \rowcolor{Gray}
    Baar -- FOOO                                        &       Nope
                                                                \begin{itemize}
                                                                    \item Item1
                                                                \end{itemize}                                               \\      \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

[image]

What is wrong with my latex? why are there no vertical and horizontal lines? What should i include in my latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `colortbl` draws the rows over the columns.

Adopt this trick.

Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

MWE (I've changed your custom colors)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {\CT@row@color}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@classz}
  {\oldCT@column@color}
  {\CT@column@color}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{7cm}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray}
    \textcolor{white}{\textit{Column 1}}                &       \textcolor{white}{\textit{Column 2}}                        \\      \hline
    Fooo -- Bar                                         &       Some text here with enum:
                                                                \begin{itemize}
                                                                    \item Item1
                                                                    \item Item2
                                                                    \item ...
                                                                \end{itemize}                                               \\      \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
    Foo -- Baar                                         &       Some text here....                                          \\      \hline
    Fooo -- Baaaar                                      &       Some other text here                                        \\      \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
    Baar -- FOOO                                        &       Nope
                                                                \begin{itemize}
                                                                    \item Item1
                                                                \end{itemize}                                               \\      \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @karlkoeller , it works really fine! Can perhaps exmaple the lines what you included there ?

Comment: @T.C. Of course. `colortbl.sty` issues `\CT@column@color\CT@row@color` in this order (format the columns and then the rows). My trick changes it to `\CT@row@color\CT@column@color` so that the columns are formatted as last.

Comment: @T.C. In simple words my trick does: `temp <- a`, `a <- b`, `b <- temp` to switch `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, I've noticed that replacing `\hline` with the appropriate one of `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` revives the horizontal lines in a table of mine that has coloured rows.

Comment: The question here asks also about the *vertical* rules which `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` disregards by design. Moreover, using a 1-to-1 replacement will clearly show some "white lines" as well, since that's how the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) draws these.

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` provides an environment `{NiceTabular}` with tools which have been designed to address that kind of problem.

With `{NiceTabular}`, you will have a perfect result in the PDF viewers (at all levels of zoom) because the colored panels are filled before the rules are drawn thanks to PGF/Tikz and informations written on the |aux| file.

However, you need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{NiceTabular}{lp{7cm}}[hvlines,colortbl-like]
\rowcolor{gray}%
\textcolor{white}{\textit{Column 1}} & \textcolor{white}{\textit{Column 2}} \\  
Fooo -- Bar                          & Some text here with enum:
                                       \begin{itemize}
                                           \item Item1
                                           \item Item2
                                           \item ...
                                       \end{itemize}                        \\ 
\rowcolor{lightgray} %
Foo -- Baar                          & Some text here....                   \\ 
Fooo -- Baaaar                       & Some other text here                 \\ 
\rowcolor{lightgray}%
Baar -- FOOO                         & Nope
                                       \begin{itemize}
                                           \item Item1
                                       \end{itemize}                        \\ 
\end{NiceTabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]